# Why is scdaemon ballooning out of control?

Tags: arch-linux, gpg, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

My system keeps getting wedged because an `scdaemon` process has been spawned that has grown to consume all free memory on the computer. (I do not use, and have never used, smart cards in the vicinity of this system, so `scdaemon` shouldn't be running at all.)

I could implement something like a cronjob that runs `pkill scdaemon` every five seconds, but I'd rather find and destroy the root issue that's causing this behavior.

What files can I check and what tools can I use to track down why this daemon keeps getting started? I've done a pstree and the most I've been able to determine is that they're getting started by `gpg-agent`, which hasn't helped. I haven't found any log that's been able to shed some light on this.

Comment: For reference, the man page is here: http://linux.die.net/man/1/scdaemon

Comment: Please always mention the version of GnuPG (and the OS) so that it is possible to replicate the problem. I can look up what version Arch linux ships. If there are any patches in the Arch version of GnupG it would also be good to know them.

Answer (score 3):

To stop `gpg-agent` from starting `scdaemon`, simply add

> disable-scdaemon

to your gpg-agent configuration file (usually `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`). This file can contain any long option you can pass to `gpg-agent` without the two leading dashes as described in gpg-agent(1), section "FILES".

Of course, informing the GnuPG guys about your problem is also a good idea so it can be fixed!

Comment: Do you mean `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`?

Comment: I've filed an issue at https://bugs.g10code.com/gnupg/issue1491 - I'm upvoting this answer (and have implemented its recommendation), but I'm not marking it as accepted because it doesn't answer the original question of *why* this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I found [these instructions for managing the scdaemon](http://www.fsij.org/doc-gnuk/stop-scdaemon.html) through gpg-agent. The client tool to do this is called gpg-connect-agent.

#### To stop SCDAEMON and let it exit, type:

```
% gpg-connect-agent "SCD KILLSCD" "SCD BYE" /bye
```